# Laravel/PHP - How to split IPv6 subnets

Tags: php, laravel, networking, ipv6

I need to split a given IPv6 subnet into smaller /64 subnets.
For instance I'd like to iterate though all possible /64 subnets in a larger /48 or /56 IPv6 subnet.

However I couldn't figure out how to archive this in Laravel/ PHP, I found a few libraries for IPv6 but none of them supports subnetting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`cidrl6`**](https://github.com/emden-norfolk/cidrl) to split a */48* or */56* into a list of */64* subnets. For example:

```
$ cidrl6 -s64 fa01:0:ac00:f00::/56
fa01:0:ac00:f00::/64
fa01:0:ac00:f01::/64
fa01:0:ac00:f02::/64
...
fa01:0:ac00:fff::/64
```

You could then read the output of this command into PHP as an array with something like [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

```php
$subnets = [];
exec("cidrl6 -s64 fa01:0:ac00:f00::/56", $subnets);
print_r($subnets);
```